# Select all options Except one from dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I want to get the values of all options of multiselect dropdown except one value 
as this: `$("#ddlAgents").val().join(',')` but except `value="NNa"` I don't want to get it even it's selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this you will need to retrieve the values manually instead of using `val()` to get them all. Try this:

```
$('#ddlAgents option:not([value="NNa"]):selected').map(function() {
   return this.value;
}).get().join(',');
```

Here's a working example:

```js
$('#ddlAgents').on('change', function() {
  var output = $(this).find('option:not([value="NNa"]):selected').map(function() {
    return this.value;
  }).get().join(',');
  console.log(output);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select multiple id="ddlAgents">
  <option value="foo">Foo</option>
  <option value="NNa">NNa</option>
  <option value="bar">Bar</option>
</select>
```